# Reboot or restart Polycom SoundPoint IP 335 from command line

Tags: voip, polycom

I have 4 Polycom SoundPoint IP 335 IP phones.  Just wondering if anyone knows if these phones can be restarted/rebooted from a command line.  They all have static IP addresses.  I do have access to the admin side via the web interface too.  Sure would be nice if I could restart these from a command line.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via sip messaging, or via a push command.  The phones must be configured to accept push messages by setting the following parameters in the config files:

```
<apps.push apps.push.alertSound="1" apps.push.messageType="5" apps.push.password="password" apps.push.serverRootURL="" apps.push.username="username">
```

Once that's in place, you can use curl to send a configUpdate to the phones:

```
curl -d "<PolycomIPPhone><Data priority=\"critical\">action:UpdateConfig</Data></PolycomIPPhone>" -H "Content-Type: application/x-com-polycom-spipx" -u username:password --digest http://192.168.1.100/push
```

In asterisk, this can be done using the following:

```
asterisk*CLI> sip notify polycom-check-cfg extension
```

Note:  there's a configuration option that can force the phone to reboot when it receives either of these commands, or reboot only when needed after pulling the new config.  Depending on what you're trying to do, you may want to look at this option.  The parameter is 'voIpProt.SIP.specialEvent.checkSync.alwaysReboot' and defaults to 0

Hope this helps